# Android: make a background for layout with squares

Tags: android, android-layout, android-background

I want to make a backgroung for a layout like the one is on the image below but I don't know how to start. I have to make a drawable but I don't know how to fill the backgroung with little squares. I hope you understand my english :)

**The sample image... I hope the squares are visible**

[image: The sample image... I hope the squares are visible]

Comment: check this out http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html